# a loop to make a medication adherence variable in R

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop

I am working with prescription data and want to generate a summary variable which measures an individuals adherence to a drug over a given period. This variable is called the Proportion Days covered (PDC). I know the steps to make the variable, but can't execute the loop at the end. The steps are outlined in a doc from Leslie et al and they give SAS code. http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/043-2007.pdf

The first step is organising your data into wide format so that each unique individual has their own row with each day they got meds and how many they got. the dataframe also has an index date, the first date that an individual picked up their prescription (entered the study) and their study end date (start date + 180days follow up). This all works fine and here is a sample dataframe. xd = date filled and days_supply=how many tabs the individual got on that date.

```
df[(1:4), c(1,2,3,4,5,6,42,43)]
                   ID       xd.1 days_supply.1       xd.2 days_supply.2       xd.3   start_dt     end_dt
1  Patient HAI0674228 2011-05-05            28 2011-05-11            28 2011-05-24 2011-05-05 2011-10-31
10 Patient HAI0937281 2011-01-06            28 2011-03-01            28 2011-03-28 2011-01-06 2011-07-04
12 Patient HAI1007704 2011-01-29            28 2011-03-01            28 2011-03-31 2011-01-29 2011-07-27
18 Patient HAI1028993 2011-05-17            30 2011-06-16            30          0 2011-05-17 2011-11-12
```

the next step which uses arrays and loops is what I'm having trouble with.

First I need to create an array with a dummy variable for each day in follow up period (180days), set each value to 0. (this will act as diary of medication coverage for each day - yes/no have tablets)

```
lapply(1:180, function(i) print(i))->days2
days2[]=0
```

#### works fine

next, I need to make two more arrays which group the xd variable and the days supply variable. the aim is that these will set the do loops; filling the diary for each individual patient.

```
df[(1:5), c(1,2,4,6,8,9)]->filldates
filldates
array(filldates)->filldates
is.array(filldates)


df[(1:5), c(1,3,5,7,8,9)]->days_supply
> days_supply
array(days_supply)->days_supply
is.array(days_supply)
```

works fine

Next is setting up the loop to get the info in each of the arrays (fill date and days suplly) to fill up the medication diary. This where I'm stuck. I want the diary to look like this

```
ID      Day 1   Day 2   Day 3   Day 4-Day29 Day 30  Day 31  Day 32  Day 33
X12344  1   1   1   1            0      0      1     1
```

I would appreciate any advice on how to set up the loop to do this please?

Thank you in advance!

Code to generate DFs used here:

```
ID=c("1234", "1233", "1235", "1222")  ###random IDs
dt_fill1=as.character(c("2011-05-05", "2011-01-06", "2011-01-29", "2011-05-17"))
days_supp1=c(28,28,28,30)
dt_fill2=as.character(c("2011-05-11", "2011-03-01", "2011-03-01", "2011-06-16"))
days_supp2=c(28,28,28,30)
st_date=as.character(c("2011-05-05", "2011-01-06", "2011-01-29", "2011-05-17"))
end_date=as.charachter(c("2011-10-31", "2011-07-04", "2011-07-27", "2011-11-12")
df=data.frame(ID, dt_fill1, days_supp1, dt_fill2, days_supp2, st_date, end_date)
df
```

More detailed df:

```
ID=c("hai0674228", "hai0937281",  "hai1007704", "hai1028993",  "hai1095329",  "hai1537305",  "hai1706893",  "hai1989514",  "hai2202516", "hai2224780")
dt_fill1=as.character(c("2011-05-05", "2011-01-06", "2011-01-29", "2011-05-17", "2011-01-11", "2011-01-26", "2011-01-06", "2011-01-10", "2011-01-07", "2011-04-26" ))
days_supp1=c(28,28,28,30, 28,30,28,28,28,30)
dt_fill2=as.character(c("2011-05-11", "2011-03-01", "2011-03-01", "2011-06-16", "2011-02-08", "2011-03-14", "0", "2011-02-04", "2011-02-05", "2011-05-17"))
days_supp2=c(28,28,28,30,28,30,0,28,28,30)
dt_fill3=as.character(c("2011-05-24",  "2011-03-28", "2011-03-31", "0", "2011-03-02", "2011-03-19", "0", "2011-03-02", "2011-03-07",  "2011-06-14"))
days_supp3=c(30,28,28,0,28,30,0,28,28,30)
dt_fill4=as.character(c("2011-06-21", "2011-04-27", "2011-04-25", "0", "2011-03-30", "2011-04-15",  "0", "2011-03-31",  "2011-03-28", "2011-06-29"))
days_supp4=c(28,28,28,0,28,30,0,28,28,30)
dt_fill5=as.character(c("0", "2011-05-20", "2011-05-23", "0",  "2011-05-02", "2011-05-12", "0", "2011-04-28", "2011-04-28", "0"))
days_supp5=c(0,28,28,0,28,30,0,28,28,0)
st_date=as.character(c("2011-05-05", "2011-01-06", "2011-01-29", "2011-05-17", "2011-01-11", "2011-01-26", "2011-01-06", "2011-01-10", "2011-01-07", "2011-04-26"))
end_date=as.character(c("2011-10-31", "2011-07-04", "2011-07-27", "2011-11-12", "2011-07-09", "2011-07-24", "2011-07-04", "2011-07-08", "2011-07-05", "2011-10-22"))
df=data.frame(ID, dt_fill1, days_supp1, dt_fill2, days_supp2, dt_fill3, days_supp3, dt_fill4, days_supp4, dt_fill5, days_supp5,  st_date, end_date)
df
```

Comment: The question is barely clear to me: 1.) What is Day1, Day2, ... in the desired result? The day after medication started, i.e. the day after `start_dt`? 2.) Is `ID` in the desired result the same as `ID` in `df`? 3.) What is the value of the actual day columns in the result? Is it the same value as in `days_supply.*`? 4.) Does the final solution have to follow the linked document or may it be more R'ish.

Comment: Hi Beasterfield - thanks for getting back to me, and apologies for clarity. Day1, Day2 etc is the medication diary. This is create using the first dummy variable. Day 1 is day1 of 180 days of follow up: so yes the day after start dt. Id is same in both examples: apologies for lack of clarity there. the value in day1, day2, is a binary value 1=med present, 0=not because it's a dummy variable. the final code does not have to mimic the linked document - I just put it there to show what I was working off.

Comment: Ok, so then one more question: Are the columns `days_supply.*` needed at all?

Comment: ask as many questions as you like! I think that yes, the days supply column is essential because, we need to fill in the diary with this info. Eg., Beasterfield gets 7 tablets on 01/01/01, he/she gets 30 tablets on 01/28/01. This means that over a 60 day follow up (jan til end Feb), Beasterfield has only 37 days supply. this is the information that i am ultimately after. however once I get the loops going I'll be able to start making proportions from the medication diary myself.

Comment: Still didn't get it: So on day1 I got 7 tablets, accordingly in column day1 there will be a `1`for being medicated. In the following days there will be a zero because there was no medication, on day28 there'll be again a `1` for getting 30 tablets (?) in one day, and so on. So if I got 37 tablets on two days in a time frame of 60 days. How should all the other day-columns for which there is no entry in the original data.frame be filled?

Comment: Oh, or does it mean the patience got the tablets handed over on a particular day and you just expect him to take consecutively every day  one tablet?

Comment: yes thats exactly it! so 7 yes (1) values from 01/01/01 until 01/07/01 then 0 after that right up until you get more tablets (one other thing to think of here is if you get a supply before you run out - but I'll tackle that once I get the first loops up).The purpose is that I will sum all the 1s you have over the follow up period, divide it by the follow up period to see your %adherence.so in the example using you and your 37 tabs i would say that you have only ~60% adherence across two months.Thank you again for taking the time to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solving the goal of calculating proportion of the 6 month supply taken. It is almost never the case that the first step is to "go wide". (Almost always the answer in R is to "go long".) Appears the "end.date" column is 6 months out from the fill_dates, so we would use the end_date from the first record as the correct end_date? (That what I am assuming. I guess you could alternatively just add 180 to the first start_dt.)

```
reshape(dat[,-6], direction="long", 
                 idvar="ID", varying=c(xd=c(2,4), supply=c(3,5) ) )
                     ID   start_dt     end_dt time         xd days_supply
HAI0674228.1 HAI0674228 2011-05-05 2011-10-31    1 2011-05-05          28
HAI0937281.1 HAI0937281 2011-01-06 2011-07-04    1 2011-01-06          28
HAI1007704.1 HAI1007704 2011-01-29 2011-07-27    1 2011-01-29          28
HAI1028993.1 HAI1028993 2011-05-17 2011-11-12    1 2011-05-17          30
HAI0674228.2 HAI0674228 2011-05-05 2011-10-31    2 2011-05-11          28
HAI0937281.2 HAI0937281 2011-01-06 2011-07-04    2 2011-03-01          28
HAI1007704.2 HAI1007704 2011-01-29 2011-07-27    2 2011-03-01          28
HAI1028993.2 HAI1028993 2011-05-17 2011-11-12    2 2011-06-16          30

rdat <- .Last.value

by(rdat, rdat$ID, function(d) sum(d$days_supply)/ 
   as.numeric(difftime(as.Date(d$end_dt)[1], as.Date(d$start_dt)[1] )))
rdat$ID: HAI0674228
[1] 0.3128492
------------------------------------------------------------ 
rdat$ID: HAI0937281
[1] 0.3128492
------------------------------------------------------------ 
rdat$ID: HAI1007704
[1] 0.3128492
------------------------------------------------------------ 
rdat$ID: HAI1028993
[1] 0.3351955
```

If you wanted the "diary" you could merge `as.Date(start_dt[1])+0:180` with a pills-remaining vector that was incremented at each fill date by the number dispensed and decremented to zero with each advancing date. I suppose you could use an R matrix for this purpose with rows for IDs and columns for dates, but would not like to code it with an R data.frame in that manner.

I will sketch out a datastructure that might work:

```
daymat <- matrix(0, nrow=4, ncol=180)
rownames(daymat) <-  tapply(as.character(rdat$start_dt), rdat$ID, "[", 1)
daymat[ , 1:10]
#           [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
2011-05-05    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
2011-01-06    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
2011-01-29    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
2011-05-17    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

And this might be the incrementing step for each prescription fill:

```
daymat[ IDseq, as.Date(start_dt)-
                  as.Date(rownames(daymat)[IDseq]) + 0:day_supply] <- 

  daymat[ IDseq, as.Date(start_dt)- 
                  as.Date(rownames(daymat)[IDseq]) +  0:day_supply] +1
```

Some days would end of being 2 or even three depending on how frequently hte fills occurred. You could then do successive subtractions from that supply row. But need to display it as 6 months on separate rows for each month.

Comment: Hi DWin. Thank you for answer and advice on long and wide formatting. Really useful. The end date variable was made by adding 180 days to the each individuals start date;that way everyone contributes the same amount of time to follow up.you could just do  by(rdat, rdat$ID, function(d) sum(d$days_supply)/ 180 here.

Comment: There is one thing though. I would like to have freedom to calculate adherence per individual month, along with per defined follow up time (the overall motivation here is to plot monthly mean adherence on a time series). the obvious solution is just to divide the days supply by 30, but this will not be accurate as it will average out the missing days. I want to pinpoint missing days to exact months-hence the diary. i guess i could just do this by doing  y(rdat, rdat$ID, function(d) sum(d$days_supply)/ 
   as.numeric(difftime(as.Date(d$xd2)[1], as.Date(d$xd1)[1] )))?

Comment: I think you need to construct a more full featured dataset with a few more records and varying fill intervals. And then say what you want output the diary to look like. I do not think making it 180 days wide is very practical, especially if you are using column labels that are 5 characters wide. (The data structure can be 180 columns wide.)

Comment: I see what you mean. and, I do have a huge dataset that will have many columns as it is. Perhaps I should make a dummy variable for 30 days (xdx+1-xdx). Calculate each persons monthly adherence for that month alone, then get the average of those adherences to go into that month on time series.horrible loop to run for every month though.I'll put a more full featured dataset above in my post.I want my output to look like R Scott Leslie's output on pg3 of the link in my original post. Sorry to refer you to the link -its the clearest way to communicate what I want.Thanks again for your input.

Comment: Good luck. I think this is a lot more than can be reasonably expected from an SO Q&A.

Comment: oh no!!!! I was hoping you wouldn't say that!!! I have put the more detailed df above just in cases - I live in hopeful optimism. Anything sas can do R can do....... Thank you for your help nonetheless. When I eventually come up with the answer I'll post it up. Still accepting help though!

Comment: There are Rhelp (and maybe SO) Q&A's on building GANTT charts that might help if you want to replicate that SAS display.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar need working with pharmacy data. One approach was to adapt the following code. Did you ever have success calculating PDC using R?

```
calc_adherence <- function(fills, year){
filldates <- as.Date(as.character(fills$FirstDateofService), format('%m/%d/%Y'))
days_supplied <- fills$DaysSupplied
first_fill <- min(filldates)
last_fill <- max(filldates)

duration <- as.Date(paste("12/31",year, sep="/"), format('%m/%d/%Y')) - first_fill + 1
med_days <- vector(mode = 'integer', length=as.numeric(duration))
for (i in seq(duration)){
  for(j in seq(length(filldates))){
    if(filldates[j] <= first_fill + i - 1 && first_fill + i - 1 <= filldates [j] + days_supplied[j] - 1)
      med_days[i] <- 1
  }
}

early_fill_days <- calc_early_fill(filldates, days_supplied)
days_covered <- sum(med_days) +early_fill_days
adh <- days_covered / as.numeric(duration)
if (adh > 1) adh <- 1
ad <- data.frame(PatientID=fills$PatientID[1], FirstFill=first_fill,     LastFill=last_fill, Duration=duration, 
                 DaysCovered=days_covered,     LastDaysSupplied=tail(days_supplied, n=1),     TotalDaysSupplied=sum(fills$DaysSupplied),
                 Method="PDC", Adherence="adh")
}
```